# webpack load module globally and call initialize function

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, karma-jasmine

I'm using webpack + typescript + karma + jasmine to run my unit tests. I have async functions and thats why I want to load [jasmin-co](https://github.com/gradecam/jasmine-co) globally and call it's `install()` function once. I don't want to require it in each spec file.

With the provide plugin or the import loader I can load it. But what's the webpack way to load and initialize a external library globally?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the best way of doing this, but you can have a look at my angular2-webpack sample application here: https://github.com/ChristianEder/angular2-webpack-aspnetcore

It involves a specs.js file that is doing two things:

- Requiring any own or third party components required to run the tests. In the sample, I intentionally require all of my productive code, in order to make code coverage analysis show all my files. If I wouldn't do this, the coverage report would only include files that actually are required by any test. Files  that are completely untested would not show up in the coverage report, otherwise.
- Requiring all the tests that have to be run.

So you could probably solve your problem by requiring the lib inside of this specs.js.

You can have a look at my [specs.js](https://github.com/ChristianEder/angular2-webpack-aspnetcore/blob/master/Frontend/test/unit/specs.js) and my [karma test config](https://github.com/ChristianEder/angular2-webpack-aspnetcore/blob/master/Frontend/test/unit/karma.test.conf.js).